# Issues with Displaying data in Spline Charts of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, spline

I am trying to display data from MYSQL in javascript highcharts using Spline chart, I am succedded in that, the chart consists of various series, usually in the spline chart of highcharts all the points should be connected, but here only first series of points are only connected, remaining series are represented as points. Can anyone suggest what to do ?

Comment: Please show code or a representative jsFiddle. Do you have connectNulls enabled? Is your series linear?

Comment: How your data does it look like ?